# Add bundle product in cart without chossing options

Tags: magento

I have website in magento and i am using bundle products with options (Simple Products). On frontend Options are displaying. I want to make thease options  optional. I have selected 
Bundle Items Is required "No" thease options in admin for this product(Thease options is not required set from admin panel). But currently i can't add this product in cart without chossing options.

Can anyone tell me the solutions

Thank

Comment: `I have selected required "No" thease options in admin for this product. But currently i can add this product in cart without chossing options.` This statement is confusing.

Comment: Thease options is  required "No" is set from admin for this product